# CSS3 Why input[type=text]'s border left and top are showing black?

Tags: css, input, border

My question is quite simple. How to set border left and top to the color I want?

```css
input.comment-input {
  width: 60%;
  border-color: #2bb6c1;
  border-width: 1px;
}

input.comment-input,
button.btn-comment {
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.1em 0.2em;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

button.btn-comment {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2bb6c1;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: dashed 1px #2bb6c1;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="comment-input">
<button type="button" class="btn-comment">input</button>
```

Here is the [**Js-Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jLnd5v8t/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `border-left` and `border-top` property for this

```
border-left:1px solid red; //set you want color
border-top:1px solid red;  //set you want color
```

```css
input.comment-input {
  width: 60%;
  border-color: #2bb6c1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

input.comment-input,
button.btn-comment {
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.1em 0.2em;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

button.btn-comment {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2bb6c1;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: dashed 1px #2bb6c1;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="comment-input">
<button type="button" class="btn-comment">input</button>
```

Comment: That's work! Thank you. So what is the proper way to set border's color?  Do I have to write border-top and border-left individually every time?

Answer (score 0):

are you missing `border-style` ?

```
   input.comment-input {
   width: 60%;
   border-color: #2bb6c1;
   border-width: 1px;
   /*border-style*/
   border-style: dashed
}
```